# Receber informações do Telebot

Tags: python, chatbot, telegram-bot

Estou desenvolvendo um bot de telegram e parte dele já está funcional. Agora, preciso receber um input do usuário com perguntas que o sistema faça para que eu possa automatizar ainda mais os processos. Na documentação, não achei como fazer isso (https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI) e nos códigos de exemplo no Github também não achei nenhum código que receba isso.

A parte do código que eu preciso receber a informação do usuário:

```
## -------------- Começa o cadastro --------------------
@bot.message_handler(commands=['vamosla'])
def send_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message, "Digite seu Nome completo: ")
    # Ler o texto digitado
    # Armazena a informação
    time.sleep(2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "O que acha de fazermos agora?\n /start: Ir para o menu principal.\n /atendimento: Ser atendido. \n /sair: Finalizar atendimento.")
```

Será que é possível receber essa informação?

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Eu tenho desenvolvido alguns telegram-bots ultimamente e tenho utilizado o framework [telepot](https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Nele, o processo de receber e enviar mensagens é muito simples e nunca tive problema.

Para iniciar o bot:

```
import telepot
bot = telepot.Bot('***** PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE *****')
```

Você pode facilmente ter acesso as novas mensagens enviadas pelos usuários através do comando:

```
updates = bot.getUpdates()[0]
chat_id = updates['message']['chat']['id']
message = updates['message']['text']
```

E para enviar a resposta é ainda mais fácil:

```
bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Hey!')
```

Espero ter ajudado! Leia a documentação para saber mais!
https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode criar uma função que receba uma mensagem do usuário e atribui-la ao `Decorator` e usar o `message.text` para gerênciar as mensagens do usuário sem precisar de um comando específico.

exemplo:

```
def receive_message(message):
if message.text == 'Oi': # verificando o input do usuario
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Olá, bem vindo ao bot') # resposta do bot
    return True

@bot.message_handler(func=receive_message) # recebendo a função receive_message
def Start(message):
    pass

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Espero que ajude e resolva o seu problema.